# Bulk email in cakephp using sendgrid

Tags: email, cakephp, dynamic, bulk, sendgrid

I am using cakePHP to send smtp email with sendgrid. I would like to be able to execute a single send() to multiple recipients and allow sendgrid to use the vars to replace -name- with the names from a array.

In my cakephp controller method I am testing:

protected function fwtEmail() {

```
    $config = 'sendGrid';
    $subject = "test";

    $Email = new CakeEmail('sendGrid');

    $names = array('user@domain.com'=>'John','user2@domain' =>'Paul');
    $Email->To($names);

    $vars = array('Paul', 'John');

    $Email->viewVars(array('name' => $vars));

    $Email->from( array('admin@testdomain.com' => 'Jim') );

    $Email->subject($subject);

    $template = 'bulk';

    $Email->template($template, 'default');

    $Email->sendAs = 'both';
    return $Email->send();

}
```

Answer (score 1):

[Here is a post on the SendGrid blog](http://sendgrid.com/blog/guest-post-sendgrid-takes-the-cakephp-when-it-comes-to-smtp/) that does what you describe.

edit: apologies, this appears not to work in the latest cakephp. I'm trying to find a solution for you.